# avatar en header de ionic-menu ioic

Tags: ionic3, ionic-framework

estoy tratando de colocar un avatar en el header de un menu en IONIC 3, pero no obtengo el resultado que deseeo.

lo que he trato de hacer es lo siguiente:

```
<ion-menu id="menuNave" [content]="miNav" padding> 
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar color="dark">
            <ion-title>Menu Versus 23</ion-title>
            <ion-list>
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-avatar item-start>
                        <img [src]="jugadorVariables2.imgperfil">
                        </ion-avatar>
                        <p>{{ jugadorVariables2.nombre }}</p>
                    </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar correctamente un ion-avatar, éste ha de estar dentro de un item. Sin embargo en tu caso sugiero realizarlo mediante una clase CSS, algo así:

```
.avatar {
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
```

Luego el html dentro del header:

```
  <div no-padding no-margin style='float:left'>
      <img class='avatar' src="..."  
  </div>
```